Where does Python questions belong to?
You could find a lot of questions with the python tag but does it belong on this site because it also about the ev3 programmable LEGO brick or is it better on Stack Overflow because it's about programming or are both valid?
I've also seen that Stack Overflow also has a "lego", "mindstorms" and "ev3" tag.

Yes, the tag belongs on this site as well. There are a number of 3rd-party firmware replacements for the Mindstorms hubs, so it makes sense for us to be able to tag questions with the language being used in the programme, especially if it's relevant to the question.
As with many programmable systems, there's going to be some cross-over between sites, however many of the questions tagged lego on StackOverflow either predate this site, or seem to be more targeted to SO with things like "How to use TensorFlow to categorise LEGO bricks" or "How to import custom python modules" on an hub ;)
